# Define a measuring function for an operator in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, types, ocaml

I would like to define an operator `l_op : A list * A list -> A list` whose implementation requires another operator `op : A * A -> A`. Given `a0: A`, though for all `a1 : A` `op a0 a1`  always returns a result as `A`, for some `a1` the result makes **more sense** than other `a1`.

Intuitively `l_op al0 al1` needs a strategy of **matching**, which finds a **meaningful** element of `al1`, with regard to `op`, for each element of `al0`. Then the list of the results by `op` is the result of `l_op`.

So I need a measure of **meaning**.

One possible choice is, a function `measure: A * A * A -> int` can be defined. For instance, `measure a0 a1 (op a0 a1)` gives an int from 1 to 10 which represents how `op a0 a1` makes sense. Then in the implementation of `l_op al0 al1`, for each `a0` of `al0`, I can find `a1` such that `measure a0 a1 (op a0 a1) >= measure a0 a1' (op a0 a1') for all a1' in al1`. Then I remove `a0` and `a1` from the two lists, and match the rest of the two lists...

Another choice is, I change a little bit `op` to `op : A * A -> A * int` where the integer represents how the operation makes sense.  Then in the implementation of `l_op al0 al1`, for each `a0` of `al0`, I can find `a1` such that `for all a1' in al1, m1 >= m1' where (_, m1), (_, m1') = op a0 a1, op a0 a1'`.

An advantage of the second choice is that, we can save some code because we can calculating the measuring while doing `op a0 a1`. A disadvantage is that I find the signature `op : A * A -> A * int` is less good-looking than `op : A * A -> A`.

So my questions are:

1) There is a conventional word for this kind of measuring function (which starts by `h` probably), but I have forgotten it, could anyone remind?

2) Do you think `int` is a good type for measuring? Maybe we can define a type for that... What is the most conventional way?

3) Which choice that I mentioned above is better? Or does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a conventional word for this kind of measuring function (which starts by h probably),

Maybe "heuristic"? It comes from the Ancient Greek for "find out, discover" and is used in computer science to name methods that look for "good enough" results, often approximating the perfect behavior in a simpler but nearly as effective way. It is really appropriate here (unless your "meaning measurement" really is an heuristic/approximation) but begins with 'h'.

I would suggest just calling your measurements a "score", or a "weight".

> Do you think int is a good type for measuring? Maybe we can define a type for that... What is the most conventional way?

In depends on how your measuring is defined. How much structure do you need on the results (eg. you could want to keep the justification of your measurement, needing a richer structure)? What kind of operations do you use while measuring? If you only use addition and constants, `int` is fine, if you use division etc., `float` may be needed. You probably need a type whose values it is possible to compare, in all cases.

I guess that `int` will be ok in most circumstances, and otherwise you'll be able to change your mind relatively easily. If you plan to change this, you can use a type alias:

```
type measure = int
```

This way you can use `measure` instead of `int` in most of your code, and don't need to replace all occurrences afterwards. That said, in OCaml we usually don't write a lot of type annotations, thanks to inference, so in practice I don't expect details of your typing choices to be spread in a lot of code.

> Which choice that I mentioned above is better? Or does anyone have a better idea?

I'd pick the second choice. I suspect there is some redundancy between the `A -> A -> A` operation of "computing the result" and the `A -> A -> int` operation of "computing the result meaning". By doing both at the same time (`A -> A -> A * int`) you can reuse the same logical structure, which makes that correspondence clearer (and uses less code). If on the contrary the two operations are totally unrelated, you can consider having two separate operator (but I'd still use `A -> A -> int` for scoring; if you need to get the result to measure meaning, you can still call the first operation internally).